# Preview option in android studio is not working

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have some issue in android studio in preview option [xml]

Details are below

I done all things.

1. Gradle already build
2. All xml layout error are removed
3. Also changed api level,screen resolution,rotation and theme
4. Restart android studio
   But couldn't happen anything 
   Image link below

[image]

Code are below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
       android:id="@+id/DT_ImageCardView"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="150dp"
       app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/DarkGrayDark"
       app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
       app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
       card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false">

       <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/DT_full_image"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
           android:contentDescription="@string/dailytipsimage"
           android:scaleType="fitXY"
           android:src="@drawable/trans_logo" />

       <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/DT_share"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_below="@id/DT_ImageCardView"
           android:background="@color/transparentBlack"
           android:contentDescription="@string/dailytipsshare"
           android:padding="5dp"
           android:src="@drawable/ic_share_white_24dp" />

   </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/DT_full_title"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_below="@id/DT_ImageCardView"
       android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
       android:text="@string/jeetesh_surana"
       android:textAlignment="center"
       android:textSize="20sp"
       android:textStyle="bold" />

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/DT_full_des"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_below="@id/DT_full_title"
       android:layout_margin="10dp" />

   <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
       android:id="@+id/DT_full_videoIV"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
       android:layout_below="@id/DT_full_des"
       android:layout_margin="10dp"
       android:padding="10dp"
       android:src="@drawable/ic_videocam_black_24dp"
       android:visibility="visible" />

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/DT_comment"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="50dp"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
       android:padding="10dp"
       android:text="@string/comment"
       android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You can update SDK version and Gradle version.

Answer (score -1):

Per first show us your issue right up corner in your screen "!"
Per second that screen meen (if i good remember) your screen not yet loaded
On my old PC was even 2-3 min before it shows:)